# Merge external sources into TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, external

We have library sources updated externally and also modify parts of the library sources inside TFS.

Is there a way to easily merge the external updates into TFS?

I was thinking of creating a branch of the current version, then checkout-edit that branch and copy the new version over it and then merge back to base. Is this a good strategy or am I overseeing something?

Comment: It's a good way to do this. Just curiouse why you update the sources externally.

Comment: @Windy: The library is third party. We adjust parts of it locally, but the vendor of course keeps releasing updates as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to branch.  You could just check out the entire set of external sources, replace with the ones you have been given and then when you do a check-in TFS will only show the files that have changes as being updated in that changeset.

Before you do the check-in, you might want to do a directory compare with the external sources in a totally isolated directory though to make sure that you delete any files that have been deleted / renamed in the external source.  [SourceGear's DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) is free and has a nice directory compare feature that would help you do that.

Comment: Thanks Martin. If I only checked out and replaced files I would not be able to merge the changes we made to that copy. As far as I understand it, TFS would commit that without merge in mind. 
What I did now was to use an arbitrary feature branch descending from our DEV branch where I would like the changes to be merged into. I copied the changed sources to the feature branch. Then I checked-out-edit (unlocked) the DEV branch and merged from feature -> DEV, which gave me the merge conflicts I needed.